# react native Scroll does not work while hold on textInput

Tags: react-native

I have android application with registration form. Its code:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <ScrollView style={{flex:1, backgroundColor='#ffffff'}}>
        <More components...>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputText} 
                   value={this.state.mail}
                   placeholder="Email"
                   onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState.(mail:text)}/>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputText} 
                   value={this.state.fName}
                   placeholder="First name"
                   onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState.(fName:text)}/>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputText} 
                   value={this.state.sName}
                   placeholder="Second name"
                   onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState.(sName:text)}/>
        <More components...>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

But when user hold tap on TextInput and begins to scroll the view  does not scroll. In other controls scroll works well.

Comment: It's suggested that it only happens if TextInput are right-aligned: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12167

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView style={{flex:1, backgroundColor='#ffffff'}}>
<View style={{flex:1}}>    
    <More components...>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputText} 
               value={this.state.mail}
               placeholder="Email"
               onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState.(mail:text)}/>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputText} 
               value={this.state.fName}
               placeholder="First name"
               onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState.(fName:text)}/>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputText} 
               value={this.state.sName}
               placeholder="Second name"
               onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState.(sName:text)}/>
    <More components...>
```

the scroll element must enclose a view